# PHP не принимает данные

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Добрый день. Отправляю ajax-запрос к PHP-файлу и вызываю его обратно в надежде получить страницу, заполненную отправленными мной данными. Однако, PHP, вместо данных, возвращает 0.

Ajax-запрос:

```
$('#krok-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'receipt/krok-receipt.php',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Data was sent successfuly');
            $('#blank-frame').html(data);
            $('#blank-frame').css({'padding' : '15px'});

            $('.must-hide').hide('slow', function(){
                $(this).detach();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP-файл принимает данные следующим образом:

```
<?php 
    $username = $_POST['user-fullname'];
    $address = $_POST['client-address'];
    $contract = $_POST['contract-id'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount-payment'];
    echo 'Приняты данные: \n' + $username + '\n' + $address + '\n' + $contract + '\n' + $amount;
?>
```

Функция echo выводит 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все потому что вы пытаетесь складывать строку как числа, при этом строки пытаются перевестись в число и становятся нулями.

Оператор конкатенации строк в PHP служит `.` (точка).

Ваша последняя строка должна быть такой:

```
echo 'Приняты данные: \n' . $username . '\n' . $address . '\n' . $contract . '\n' . $amount;
```

И как вариант, можно использовать запись вида:

```
echo implode("\n", array ('Приняты данные:',  $username, $address, $contract, $amount));
```

Тогда каждый параметр переданный в массиве, будет приведен к строке разделенному символом указанным первым параметром.

В этом случае символом переноса строки `\n`

Comment: Либо `echo implode("\n", array ('Приняты данные:', $username,$address,$contract,$amount));`   Суть та же, но, в иных случаях короче выходит.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов отличное решение для записи, если каждую строку (как в этом случае) нужно перенести, добавлю в ответ

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов да, теперь выводится строка "Получены данные:" и всё. Мои данные, переданные через ajax-запрос - не отображаются. И скорее всего, проблема в том, что данные отправляются из модального окна, содержимое которого так же загружено при помощи ajax. Я могу ошибаться, конечно, но мучаюсь с этой проблемой уже битые сутки.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin посмотрите что вам приходит в `print_r($_POST)`. Там скорее всего строка в формате `json`. И вам нужно будет её распарсить с помощью `json_decode`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев на экран выводится пустой массив. **Array ()**

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin используйте, например, var_dump($_POST), что бы убедиться, что данные вообще приходят. Если они там есть, проверьте имена, если нет — проверьте исходный html

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов попробовал, выводит пустой массив. Видимо, данные-таки не приходят. Буду разбираться с формой.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов проверил форму, всё правильно. Всё-таки, может, дело в том, что данные отправляются из формы, которая так же была загружена при помощи ajax?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin как Вы проверили форму? var_dump выдал искомое? Уточняйте же ж.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов я разобрался в своей проблеме. Оказывается, что данные из инпутов берутся не по id, а по name. Всё равно, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin фига-се «всё равно».

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin отметьте вопрос как верный, поставив галочку, если ответ ответил на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

А у вас точно такие значения атрибута name? 
И я бы на вашем месте посмотрел бы на результат print_r($_POST)

Что он выводит?